# Logging Apache downloads to DB?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have a website hosting a lot of Document files (PDF, XLS, ETC). I frequently get requests for a tally of downloads per month for specific files. Historically, I've just used sed,awk and brethren to grep the apache logs for the desired filename along with entries containing 'GET' and a 200 status code then piping the whole thing to wc.

People are now wanting historical tallies going back through years of logs. Combing through log files takes a lot of time and resources.  I'm wondering if there is an apache mod or something similar which will log those GET requests to a database?

Comment: and why you don't want to create a simple script bash/php/python (whatever you like) that would parse apache access log (you could run ot via cron every x minutes) and put all necessary information to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Do some Click Tracking...and log the clicks you want to a database going forward.  For going backwards and collecting from logs, I am no help.

A simple js function for a clicks will log that info.

Include this function on your pages that will post all those requests to a php file:

```
$('a').bind('click', function() {
      //alert('User clicked on "foo."');
      var e_name = this.name;
      var curr_url = document.URL;
      var to_url = this.href;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "inc/trackit.php",
          data: { name: e_name, url: curr_url, to_url: to_url, uid: uid }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
          //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
```

The php file that actually posts to the DB could look like this:

```
<?
include "db_con.php";

$e_name = $_POST['name'];
$curr_url = $_POST['url'];
$to_url = $_POST['to_url'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];

$track = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO logs (uid, name, url, to_url, create_date)
        VALUES ('$uid','$e_name','$curr_url','$to_url' ,now())
        ");

?>
```

Now, so long as all your links have a "name" tag, you will get them logged.

Comment: Neet Idea! I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the example